# facebook grapg api Get Comments from the post working only for my developer account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have created an App for getting random comment on a post from facebook.
user first log in with facebook then enter the url of the post and and click search. then press shuffle button to show a random comment on that post.

after that user can post that random comment and the person who made that comment on their facebook feed/Wall.

all this functionality is working when i login with my developer ID, but no other facebook user can do that. I have made sure that my app is live and available for public. and i have also approved needed permissions from facebook. following are my available permissions:

email
public_profile
publich_action
user_friends
user_posts

please tell me where i am going wrong.
website: www.1canwin.com

[Facebook permissions granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlQfv.png)

Comment: _“please tell me where i am going wrong”_ - can’t, because you have hardly given us any actually useful or relevant information at all. Please go read [ask].

Comment: @CBroe you want me to show code or website i created?

Comment: are you sure you went through login review with those permissions?

Comment: yes, i have logged in and checked all the functionality of the app, its working fine when i login with the facebook ID that i used as developer of this app. the other persons can also login but it does not fetch any data in their case. @luschn

Comment: we know that, but did you go through the login review process and got publish_actions and user_posts specifically approved by facebook? please show us a screenshot of the review page in the app settings.

Comment: I have edited my post with granted facebook permission snap, as you said. Please check @luschn

Comment: That’s _approved_, not “granted”. The individual user is the one who has to _grant_ those permissions to your app. And for that to happen, you must ask them to do so via the login dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to @luschn

you need to ask for permissions from the user first, you can do it with following line of code:

$permissions = ['email,publish_actions']

permission names are separated by commas.